# IPhone Development - Setting Background Image For IPad From A Downloaded Image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, ipad, background

I am new to this and have searched a lot this week. I am trying to set a background image from a file I have downloaded from a url. I need to save the image for later. Specially if I am not connected to the internet I can still show this image.

I have validated by printing out the contents of the directory that the file exists. This is one of many code that I have tried to make the image appear in the background.

```
nNSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *documentPath = [docDir stringByAppendingFormat:@"/mainback.png"];

// If you go to the folder below, you will find those pictures

NSLog(@"%@",documentPath);



if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:documentPath]) {

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:documentPath];

    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

    NSLog(@"WHAT - %f,%f",image.size.width,image.size.height);

    UIColor *background = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:documentPath]];

    self.view.backgroundColor = background;

    [background release];

}
```

The code finds the image in the directory but I cannot set the image to the background. Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [UIImageView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (Apple documentation linked) instead of doing what you are trying to do with UIColor.

It'll be a lot more straightforward and less problematic.

Comment: I need it as a background image as I have to display a form on the front of it. Can i use UIImageView to display background images? Didnt find any example of it on the web tho. Thanks for your help